# SQL to calculate percentage based on 2 columns from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

How to calculate percentage of room area per each building? I have 2 tables: Buildings and Rooms. Each Room in Rooms table has and Area in square meters:

```
Rooms Table
Room    Area  Building FKey
Room1   10    BK
Room2   20    CK

Building Table
PKey Name
BK  Building1
CK  Building2


Result
Building  area (%)
Building 1  10%
Building 2  30%
```

Comment: Where is the total building area stored?

Comment: How is the percentage calculated?  It is not obvious from the question.

Comment: There is no total building area. Building has rooms, in Rooms table. This table has areas stored under each room. I want to sum the totals of each room and display it against each building.

Comment: Percentabe I think should be  calculated by sum(Rooms. Area)/Count(Building.BuildingName)*100, but it doesnt give me right number.

Comment: If there is no total area per building, you can **not** calculate a percentage. Do you simply want the **sum** of the areas per building? (Your proposed formula in the comment seems to assume every building is 100 square meters, which seems strange)

Comment: I can get the sum for each building but how to get the proportion in %

Comment: Proportion in % = sum of areas / **Total Area**. If you do not have the total area, you can **NOT** calculate the percentage. Never. Impossible. Or do you want to know what percentage of the total area of all buildings each building represents? (In other words, for building1, that percentage would be `100 * 10 / 40 = 25%`? )

Comment: I just did this in Crystal reports: Total area (%) of all buildings: 100%, Total area of all buildings 97,861.21. Building one - 18,20% Area-17,814.79, Building two - 13.16%, area 12,883.16 ....etc.

Comment: Yes you right I need total area.

Comment: So total area in your example is 30, and the percentages in your example (in your question) are nonsense? Please **update** your question with more detail and actual examples of what you expect.

Comment: Yes, I didn't put the right percentage. I disn't realise this is necessary, I thought it will give an idea what I need to get

Comment: I wrote an answer based on 25% and 75% in your original example. In general, it's a good idea to try and give the exact result you expect, because otherwise people might not undertsand what you want :)

Comment: -1 : so much devotion for a bad question, we re not your lackey, ask an understandable question and show us what you have already tried then we ll help.

Answer (score 0):

Am I understanding right that you want the percentage of each room to the building?  Or do you want to see the total of rooms for each building?

If the latter, you will need to bind the total building area.

If the former, something like this should work...  You basically need to compute the total area of each building and divide the Rooms Area by that.

```
SELECT Building.Name, 
       Rooms.Name,
    100.0 * Area / (SELECT SUM(R2.Area) FROM Rooms R2 WHERE R2.BuildingID = Rooms.BuildingID) AS Percentage
FROM Rooms
    INNER JOIN Building     
        ON Rooms.BuildingID = Building.BuildingID
```

If the latter, then something like this (even though you haven't specified where the total building area is stored... assuming on the building table):

```
SELECT BuildingID, SUM(Rooms.Area) / Building.Area * 100.0
FROM Rooms
    INNER JOIN Building     
        ON Rooms.BuildingID = Building.BuildingID
GROUP BY Building.BuildingID
```

Comment: So every building is exactly 100 square meters?

Comment: If each building has only one room, then each room is 100% of the building.

Comment: The former scenario would produce 100% for both rooms in the example, which is not what the OP specified.

Comment: So why not `select '100%' as percentage`, then? I find it amazing one can answer this question without knowing where the percentage should come from ...

Comment: The OP does not include a `Building.Area` column, upon which you rely in your latter scenario.

Comment: @eggyal Yeah... noted now... just assumed that would be where it was stored.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Each building has many rooms. I only gave 2 examples. Each room can have any square meterage. I need to see the total of rooms area for each building. For example this query I created gives me area of rooms for each building but I need this number in % :

Comment: select BG_SITE AS BUILDING, sum(Area )AS Percent from Rooms
inner join Buildings on BG_SEQ=LO_FKEY_BG_SEQ 
GROUP BY BG_SITE
ORDER BY  Percent DESC

Comment: I tried this , but it does give right number:select BG_SITE AS BUILDING, sum (Area)/COUNT(BG_SITE)*100 AS Percent from Rooms 
inner join Buildings on Buildings.BuildingID = Rooms.BuildingID
 group by Buidling ORDER BY Percent DESC, i get numbers like: 5276.28148148148

Comment: @SimonaSopagaite The COUNT(BG_SITE) probably returns a value of 1.  So, you want the total Room Area as a percentage of the total building area?  If so, we have to figure out where to get the building area.  I'm assuming the building area is larger than the sum of the room areas as the building area includes hallways, bathrooms, closets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I finally understand what percentage you want to calculate (the total area per building / total area of all buildings), you could try something like this:

```
SELECT Building.Name, 
       100.0 * Sum(Room.Area) / (SELECT SUM(R2.Area) FROM Rooms R2) 
       AS Percentage
FROM Rooms INNER JOIN Building     
     ON Rooms.BuildingID = Building.BuildingID
GROUP BY Building.Name
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct answer! thank you very much! sorry i wasnt' clear with my question it's my first time here!

Comment: You'd be better off joining your correlated subquery to the parent, rather than having MySQL repeat it for each record.